# Google-Apps-Scripts Function Call return parameter

Tags: parameters, function-call

Help.

I use a google sheet where each row contains a pair of coordinates in the UK's Grid system  (east & north). These pairs are converted to latitude & longitude by calling a function NEtoLL - shown in outline below.

The intent is to take an east,north pair from adjacent cells in a row and replace the NEtoLL function call and the next cell in the same row with the latitude & longitude values. I used this some years ago and I am sure it all worked OK - but I would say that wouldn't I!

The PROBLEM ... However now the returned values are being placed in the function call cell and the cell beneath this in the next row. This fails where the next row contains the NEtoLL function call to that rows east, north pair as it cannot overwrite this value.

It does work for the last row where it correctly replaces the function call with the latitude and the cell beneath this with the longitude.

How do I return the values so they are placed in adjacent cells in the same row.

Many thanks
Paul

```
function NEtoLL(east, north) 
{
  // converts NGR easting and nothing to lat, lon.
  // input metres, output signed degrees 
  var nX = Number(north);
  var eX = Number(east);
// ... lots of serious maths code (which I have removed) to convert from UK's Grid Ref System to Lat Long WGS84

  var geo = transform(phip, lambdap, OSGB_AXIS, OSGB_ECCENTRIC, 0, WGS84_AXIS, WGS84_ECCENTRIC, 446.448, -125.157, 542.06, 0.1502, 0.247, 0.8421, -20.4894);

  var res = new Array(2);
  res[0] = geo.latitude * rad2deg;
  res[1] = geo.longitude * rad2deg;

  return res; // return(geo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you could do this. Simplest, quickest for you might be to duplicate the function, so you would have now 2 nearly identical functions that output one of either latitude, or longitude. Then use them in different columns.

```
function NEtoLatitude(east,north) { 
 // your input assignments 
 // your lots of serious maths code

var res = geo.latitude * rad2deg; 
return res 
} 

function NEtoLongitude(east,north){ 

 // your same input assignments 
 // your same lots of serious maths code

var res = geo.longitude * rad2deg; 
return res 
}
```

Your problem is that you output an array, and those fill downward in the column. In this solution, you would use NEtoLatitude in one column, and NEtoLongitude in the next column. Each only outputs a single desired value and, thus corresponding latitude and longitude are located in the same intended row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a multi dimensional array.
This will put the output in a new column rather than a new row.

```
function example(input) {

  res = [];//creates array

  res[0] = [];//creates array in 1st position of res array
  res[0][0]="first";//populates 1st position of nested array 
  res[0][1]="row";//populates 2nd position of nested array

  //as an example the following would populate the next row down
  res[1] = [];
  res[1][0]= "new";
  res[1][1]= "row";

  return res;

}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output of example() - with the function in A1 (sorry it won't let me post images.)

[Google sheets](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lROBOF6NIBw/WUzEvP8ACiI/AAAAAAAAEP0/ZYfWGzJedEsVnj96EniXGzuXksCVIKLqACLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot.jpg)

So you need both items to be in the same (1st) position of the array.

```
  res = [];// equivalent to your var res = new Array(2);
  res[0] = [];//creates array in 1st position of res array
  res[0][0] = geo.latitude * rad2deg;
  res[0][1] = geo.longitude * rad2deg;

  return res;
```

Walling Rich

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for both replies. Both work. I prefer Walling Rich's solution given it provides a single call to the NEtoLL function per UK grid ref pair and addresses the original problem head-on.

Now to see if I can pass a range to NEtoLL and have a range of values returned so only one server side call is made.

Thanks again.
Paul